# Azure Container Registry - delete all images except 2

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I want to delete all images in Azure Container Registry except the last two. I was looking for an script for do so but I only find to delete images older than X days. This is not possible for my situation because some days there are a lot of images created and other days only one.

Somebody has any idea?

Comment: you should explain a) what you mean by "last two" and b) what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 11):

Modify the values for $skipLastTags & $registryName to your choice and run this script on powershell.

Note: Please verify that you have az cli installed on your local system.

```
$registryName = 'registryName'
$doNotDeleteTags = ''
$skipLastTags = 4

$repoArray = (az acr repository list --name $registryName --output json | ConvertFrom-Json)

foreach ($repo in $repoArray)
{
    $tagsArray = (az acr repository show-tags --name $registryName --repository $repo --orderby time_asc --output json | ConvertFrom-Json ) | Select-Object -SkipLast $skipLastTags

    foreach($tag in $tagsArray)
    {

        if ($donotdeletetags -contains $tag)
        {
            Write-Output ("This tag is not deleted $tag")
        }
        else
        {
            az acr repository delete --name $registryName --image $repo":"$tag --yes
        }
 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need this in `bash`.

The variable `delete_from` is 1-index based, i.e. if you specify the value 1, all images will be deleted.
A value of 3 keeps the 2 latest images.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

acr='your_acr'
repos=('repo1' 'repo2' 'repoN')
delete_from=3

for repo in "${repos[@]}"; do
    tags_to_delete=$(echo $(az acr repository show-tags -n ${acr} --repository ${repo} --orderby time_desc --output tsv) | cut -d ' ' -f${delete_from}-) 
    for tag_to_delete in ${tags_to_delete}; do
        az acr repository delete --yes -n ${acr} --image ${repo}:${tag_to_delete}
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to test it right now but this little PowerShell script should work:

```
$acrName = 'YourACRName'

$repo = az acr repository list --name $acrName
$repo | Convertfrom-json | Foreach-Object {
    $imageName = $_
    (az acr repository show-tags -n $acrName --repository $_ | 
        convertfrom-json )| Select-Object -SkipLast 2 | Foreach-Object {
        az acr repository delete --yes -n $acrName --image "$imageName:$_"
        }
}
```

It retrieves all tags for each repository, skips the last 2, then it iterates over each tag and deletes it.

Please test it in some kind of *test environment* first.

Comment: Hello Martin, sorry for my late reply. I have 6 repositories so I also want to set the repository. Is this possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: any idea? Thanks in advance! Regards

Comment: Your solution was really helpful. I have one condition to add which should skip few image and it should not be deleted, even it is coming in deletion list. For example i have some image like `abc:v1, def:v2,xyz:v4` which should not be deleted in any case which i can add as a hard code value so that system not delete that. In the below solution if we can add a condition to skip some hardcoded image given so that these will not be deleted. May be under forach block we can add a condition and add list of image which should be skipped?

Comment: @RajivMishra Thanks for the Feedback. I agree that this would be helpful but the question was about skipping the last two images so it would be a wrong answer to this question. In general, you just have to add a `| Where-Object {$_ -notin $yourListOfImagesToKeep}` after the `ConvertFrom-Json`

Answer (score 0):

If with "the last two" you mean the *newest* two, then this should do the trick:

```
az acr repository show-manifests --name your_acr --repository your_repo --orderby time_desc -o tsv --query '[].digest' | sed -n '3,$ p' | xargs -I% az acr repository delete --name your_acr --image your_repo@% --yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in acr purge command:

**Powershell**

```
$subscription = "your-subscription-id"
$registry = "your-registry"
$PURGE_CMD = "acr purge --filter 'acs-weather-api:.*' --keep 2 --ago 0d --untagged"
az acr run --cmd $PURGE_CMD --registry $registry --subscription $subscription  /dev/null
```

**Bash**

```
SUBSCRIPTION="your-subscription-id"
REGISTRY="your-registry"
PURGE_CMD="acr purge --filter 'acs-weather-api:.*' --keep 2 --ago 0d --untagged"
az acr run --cmd "$PURGE_CMD" --registry "$REGISTRY" --subscription "$SUBSCRIPTION"  /dev/null
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge#use-the-purge-command)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @Christian Holm Jørgensen

Now you can have list to be saved (save_list).

```
#!/bin/bash -e

acr='MY_ACR_NAME'
repos=('MY_REPO') # 'repo2' 'repoN')

save_list="0.2.0-alpha.1 latest 1.0.0"

string_remove_pattern() {
      echo "${1//$2}"
    }

for repo in "${repos[@]}"; do
    tags_available=$(echo $(az acr repository show-tags -n "${acr}" --repository "${repo}" --orderby time_desc --output tsv)) 
    for to_save in $save_list; do
      tags_available=$(string_remove_pattern "$tags_available" "$to_save")
    done

    tags_to_delete=$tags_available
    echo -e "The follow image, from ACR $acr and repos $repos, will be deleted:\n$tags_to_delete"
    read -rp "Is the list of image to delete correct? (Y/N)" answer
    if [ "$answer" == "Y" ]; then
      for tag_to_delete in ${tags_to_delete}; do
          az acr repository delete --yes -n "${acr}" --image "${repo}":"${tag_to_delete}"
      done
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`acr purge`](https://github.com/Azure/acr-cli)'s `--keep` option to achieve that.

> Please note that acr-cli is not a part of az-cli yet, you need to build it from the source or use from a docker image.

For example, to keep 3 images;

```bash
acr purge \
    --registry <Registry Name> \
    --filter <Repository Filter/Name>:<Regex Filter> \
    --keep 3
```

You can also combine this with days ago filter:

```bash
acr purge \
    --registry <Registry Name> \
    --filter <Repository Filter/Name>:<Regex Filter> \
    --ago 30d \
    --keep 3
```

For more information, please refer to the [acr-cli repo](https://github.com/Azure/acr-cli).