# Script to delete old images from Azure container registry

Tags: python, image, azure-container-registry, docker-cleanup

I want to remove some unwanted tags/images from various repositories of azure container registry. I want to do all these programmatically. For example, what I need is:

- Authenticate with ACR
- List all repositories
- List all tags of each repository
- Remove unwanted images with particular tags.

Normally these operations can be done using Azure CLI and `az acr` commands. Maybe I can create a PowerShell script with `az acr` commands to accomplish this.

But can I do this with python? Is there something like Graph API to do these operations?

I found this API for ACR but allows to only delete entire registry. It doesn't allow repository-specific operations:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/

I tried with docker registry API: 
https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

```
#!/bin/bash

export registry="myregistry.azurecr.io"
export user="myusername"
export password="mypassword"

export operation="/v2/_catalog"

export credentials=$(echo -n "$user:$password" | base64 -w 0)

export catalog=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Basic $credentials" https://$registry$operation)
echo "Catalog"
echo $catalog
```

But an error is returned all the time:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"registry","Name":"catalog","Action":"*"}]}]}
```

How can I properly authenticate with ACR before using Docker registry API?

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-delete?

Comment: Yes, all that uses az acr commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For authenticate to the ACR, you can just use the Basic Authentication method with the user and password. And the format should like this:

```
curl -v -u $user:$passwd https://yourACRName.azurecr.io:443/v2/_catalog
```

For the user and password, I will suggest you use the service principal to authenticate. You can follow the steps in [Azure Container Registry authentication with service principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal). Take a look at the [roles for the ACR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles). The `Contributor` role is the appropriate one with enough permission to **List all repositories**, **List all tags of each repository** and **Remove unwanted images with particular tags**. The admin credential is not recommended because of the admin permission.

Comment: Thanks. The basic authentication works with the username and password created for ACR in the access keys section. I hope the service principal will also work. I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @AnjanaDyna Yeah, it also works. Actually, the service principal works like the user and password.

Comment: @CharlesXu Not relevant to this question. Can you have a look at my question related to acr [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73544528/how-to-update-security-patches-in-azure-container-registry-automatically) in your free time?

Answer (score 1):

This answer to this question has a sample to help with deleting:  [Azure Container Registry - delete all images except 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57579940/azure-container-registry-delete-all-images-except-2)

Basic authentication should work when using an admin users credentials.