# How to update security patches in azure container registry automatically?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry, azure-container-service, azure-security

**Scenario:**

1. There is an azure container registry(acr) with many repositories (around 20)
2. Each repository has different tags like image:dev0.1, dev0.2, prod0.1, prod0.2
3. There are more than 100 images which include all available tags within each repository

I know about the `acr` task, which can be used to update an image automatically when we update its base image.

In my scenario, I need to create more than 100 `acr` tasks for each tag and also maintain a backup of old images for recovery in case of production failures.

I would like to know, Is there any standard and/or simple way to deal with this case?