# Azure Container Registry retention policy

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, retention, acr

I have an ACR and it contains docker images for my production and development environments. Since every day there are new images being pushed I'm trying to set a retention policy. My exact use case is as below,

[image: ACR Usage]

According to the image, let's say I have 100 images in the ACR and the 100th image is consumed by the development environment. However, the production runs with the 40th image. That being said, I need to keep current and the last 2 images of the production environment as well as the development environment. For example, I need to keep the 38th, 39th, and 40th images as well as 98th, 99th, and 100th images.

I tried using `acr purge`. Unfortunately, I cannot use either the retention policy or the acr purge for my use case (as per my understandings and maybe I'm wrong).

Can anyone help me with this scenario? Please let me know if you need further information or the requirement is vague!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if the below script using azure CLI command gives an idea to work :

Which uses [Delete by tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-delete#delete-by-tag) method. For this You need to have azure cli installed on your system.

```
$registryName = 'registryName'
$doNotDeleteTags = ''
$skipLastTags = 3

$repoArray = (az acr repository list --name $registryName --output json | ConvertFrom-Json)

foreach ($repo in $repoArray)
{
    $tagsArray = (az acr repository show-tags --name $registryName --repository $repo --orderby time_asc --output json | ConvertFrom-Json ) | Select-Object -SkipLast $skipLastTags

    foreach($tag in $tagsArray)
    {

        if ($donotdeletetags -contains $tag)
        {
            Write-Output ("This tag is not deleted $tag")
        }
        else
        {
            az acr repository delete --name $registryName --image $repo":"$tag --yes
        }
 
    }
}
```

Reference: [Azure Container Registry - delete all images except 2 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57579940/azure-container-registry-delete-all-images-except-2)

(Or)

```
az acr repository show-tags -n MyRegistry --repository MyRepository
 | ConvertFrom-String 
| %{$_.P2 -replace "[",]",""} 
| where {$_ -notin "skipthistag","andthistag" } 
| % {az acr repository delete --name MyRegistry --image MyRepository:$_ --yes}
```

Reference: [How to delete image from Azure Container Registry - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446962/how-to-delete-image-from-azure-container-registry/48660339#48660339)

---

References for- Skip last x images:

1. [Cleaning up (ACR) |  Andrew Kelleher](https://medium.com/azure-architects/cleaning-up-azure-container-registry-acr-5409b41fea1a)
2. [powershell script to delete old ACR image - Microsoft
   Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/186849/schedule-powershell-script-to-delete-old-acr-image.html)

Other references:

1. [acr-cleanup:(github.com)](https://github.com/goyalmohit/acr-cleanup)
2. [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57655112/script-to-delete-old-images-from-azure-container-registry)
3. [(ACR): Tags, Manifests and Cleanup | by Anant Vardhan | Medium](https://medium.com/@anantvardhan.04/azure-container-registry-acr-cleanup-dfeb8a8bb6a9)

Comment: Hi @kavyasaraboju-MT,

I'm trying to get this done with bash script by filtering the prod image and the previous 4 images as follows,

`image_tags=$(az acr repository show-manifests --name $REGISTRY --repository $REPOSITORY --top 5 --orderby time_desc -o tsv --query "[?timestamp <= '$TIMESTAMP'].[tags[0]]")`

And then I can set the `--write-enabled` flags to false for those images and then run an `az acr purge` command to remove the other images except the latest and locked images.

Comment: However, I'll try out your logic and let you know and will mark it as answered if that helps me!.

Comment: This is one way of doing it. But in order to achieve the exact scenario I had to find a totally new way. I will write a blog about it and will attach the link here later.