# Azure container registry repository image custom cleanup

Tags: bash, shell, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

Is there any way to enable retention policy for Azure ACR repositories, where only last 3 tags is need to keep and rest can be deleted. Also we have to exclude certain images from these repositories ( can be filtered with regex  filter, eg: images have prefix "base-image")

Comment: Have you tried that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge?

Comment: Azure Container Registry (ACR) supports retention policies that can automatically delete images that are not needed. To do this, you can create an ACR task that runs the  `acr purge`  container command with the appropriate filters and retention policy settings. However, there isn't a built-in retention policy that specifies the retention of a specific number of tags like "only keep the last 3 tags."
To implement a custom cleanup policy that retains only the last 3 tags for each repository, you would typically need to create a custom script

Comment: References:[Automatically purge images from an Azure container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge) [Manage registry size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-best-practices#manage-registry-size)
[Delete container images in Azure Container Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-delete#delete-container-images-in-azure-container-registry)
[Auto cleanup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/616459/azure-acr-automatic-cleaning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delete operation to delete the tags prior.

[Acr Delete tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-delete#delete-by-tag)

Check whether the below Azure `CLI` script provides insights to meet your functionality.

```
$reg = 'xxxx'
$skipLastTags = 3
$repositories = (az acr repository list --name $reg --output json | ConvertFrom-Json)
foreach ($repo in $repositories)
{
    $tags = (az acr repository show-tags --name $reg --repository $repo --orderby time_asc --output json | ConvertFrom-Json ) | Select-Object -SkipLast $skipLastTags
    foreach($tag in $tags)
    {
            az acr repository delete --name $reg --image $repo":"$tag --yes
 
    }
}
```

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70378444/19785512) for more relevant information on your requirement.

Comment: can we get equivalent bash cl command for this ?

Comment: @Vowneee Provided command is bash command only.

Comment: I meant the script is PowerShell, and awe are unable to execute that in linux machines so looking for a way to convert them to shell script.

Answer (score 0):

From @Jahnavi's solution provided, created a shell script as below to solve our requirement.

```
#!/bin/bash

reg='xxxx'
skipLastTags=xxx
repositories=$(az acr repository list --name $reg --output json | jq -r '.[]')

for repo in $repositories; do
    tags=$(az acr repository show-tags --name $reg --repository $repo --orderby time_asc --output json | jq -r '.[]' | head -n -"$skipLastTags")
    
    for tag in $tags; do
        az acr repository delete --name $reg --image "$repo:$tag" --yes
    done
done
```